# JQuery ReplaceWith() function -- Table

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I am very new to JQuery and I cannot seem to get my replaceWith() function to act how I want it to.

Goal:
Replace a button (button1) with a form table (table1). I placed button1 inside its own div within a main contentholder div (my wrapper). Table1 is hidden but also in its own div, just somewhere else on the page.

What I am trying:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#buttondiv").replaceWith("#tablediv").show;
    });
});
```

Comment: The button does go away, but where my table should be, there is just plain text saying "#table1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this` within the click handler to refer to the clicked `#button1` element. Try this:

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    var $table = $('#table1').show();
    $(this).replaceWith($table1);
});
```

Comment: Yes, this worked for me... huh... could you help me understand why my code was wrong? PS -- THANKYOU! :D

Comment: Firstly, the `show` was missing the brackets to actually call the function, and secondly you would be calling it on the `buttondiv` which would already have been shown.